# Fluent-NHibernate Querying without loading

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

i'm trying to do a fast update query without loading the updated value
i tried to use this code

```
 public void Save(int PlayerID, string Column, object Value)
        {
            using (ISession session = new SessionManager(_connectionString).Open())
            {
                IQuery query = session.CreateQuery("UPDATE Players SET " + Column + "= :newValue WHERE PlayerID=:PlayerID");
                query.SetParameter("newValue", Column);
                query.SetParameter("PlayerID", PlayerID);
                query.ExecuteUpdate();
            }
        }
```

but i get error Player is not mapped while its actually mapped and i already using it in another statements.

Comment: Did you have mapped Player or Players? I guess that the **s** *(Players)* at the end in your UPDATE statement could be the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your entity name is `Player` and not Player**s** right?

```
IQuery query = session.CreateQuery("UPDATE Player SET " + Column + "= :newValue WHERE PlayerID=:PlayerID");
            query.SetParameter("newValue", Column);
            query.SetParameter("PlayerID", PlayerID);
            query.ExecuteUpdate();
```

you don't have to specify the name of the table in hql, just the name of the entity.

Apart from that you can work with proxies, simply use `session.Load(...)` to load a proxy object for the given id. This will not hit the database. But you can use the proxy to `session.Delete` the object.

See more details here:
http://nhibernate.info/blog/2009/04/29/nhibernate-the-difference-between-get-load-and-querying-by-id.html

Comment: but to use session.load i should use the same session for all statements ?

Comment: yes that's right, but I mean, you can always use load in each session, it will just create a proxy object which has the ID, nothing else until you access any property it will not hit the Database...
If the object is already in the session it will simply return that one of cause